# jQuery parseJSON get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token"

Tags: jquery

I was doing some stuff with jQuery parseJSON function.

This is the code, which is not working

```js
<script>

  function uploadPictureimage(file, data, id){
  console.log(data);
  var data = $.parseJSON(data);
<script>
```

I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token".

the result of console.log like this

```
{
  "id": "18668",
  "path": "/Uploads/Picture/2016-03-29/56fa7d8da1480.jpg",
  "url": "",
  "md5": "e4fcdc5209daf91b77f061bf9a71403a",
  "sha1": "b83d35bcdbe01fdbeec1bc7f238eb88d21cf8466",
  "status": 1,
  "create_time": "1459256717",
  "info": "\u4e0a\u4f20\u6210\u529f",
  "data": ""
}
```

Comment: you did not close the function body

Comment: And `data` is already JSON-parsed anyway?!

Comment: what is `console.log(data)`?